# user to be able to enter their own values in addition to those listed in combobox of datagridview in windows application C#?

Tags: c#

I want the user to be able to enter their own values in addition to those listed, in a combobox of a datagrid view.

Any suggestions how to do this???

Thanks

Comment: show me what code you have so far please

Comment: What kind of Windows application? What are the entered values used for? You need to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to setup a SelectCommand, DeleteCommand, UpdateCommand, Insertcommand. And depending if its binded to a database you would need to put it inbetween a

We need to see what you have so far, could you post your code?